How to ignore SIGHUP signal in Rust
I am trying to find a way to ignore the SIGHUP signal. I need to make sure that if the terminal is closed, the program continues to run until the end.
I saw that there are the following crates for signal processing: signal-hook , ctrlc (which can handle SIGHUP).
But I don't understand how you can ignore SIGHUP
Example:
The utility counts seconds and writes them to a file line by line.
If I close the terminal, the program will continue to count seconds and the file will continue to be updated.

Try just registering an empty handler.

Given your use case, you should not let your program ignore SIGHUP at all, but rather run it via nohup if you intend to leave the interactive session after its invocation.
